# Query to get only numbers from a cell - Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, numeric

I have a huge column in Snowflake named "AGE" and 5% of the rows have values like ">80".

I want to filter by people with AGE between [40 55] and I am facing an error "Numeric value '>80' is not recognized".

I was trying to filter using something like "where ISNUMERIC(PAT_AGE_YR_NBR)=1" but ISNUMERIC is not recognized in Snowflake.
I want to either:

- select the rows that are only numerical or
- retrieve the value out of them, like in the case ">80", I want to filter by only the numerical part of the cell, "80".

Any ideas?
cheers

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data stored in AGE column and the SELECT statement you tried?

Answer (score 2):

1. For the first part you can use [TRY_TO_NUMERIC](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_decimal.html) function as detailed in the mentioned documentation.

2. And then from the result you may then do a filter for the values where NULL is coming and have only the specific results listed.

For eg:

```
select try_to_numeric(col) as a from numtest where a IS NOT NULL and a > 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `TRY_` function:

```
WHERE TRY_CAST(PAT_AGE_YR_NBR AS INT) between 40 and 55
```